# Fragment LIfecycle in Custom Tab View

Tags: android

I have a custom widget that performs FragmentTransaction.replace when buttons are pressed. Currently, my code is set up such that the first time a fragment is created, it attaches a bunch of stuff to the view that isn't originally part of the xml layout file.

When the app first launches, all my fragments show stuff correctly, however, let's say I start on Fragment A. I can then transition to Fragment B (with B showing up correctly), however, when I transition back to Fragment A, all the stuff I have attached to the view of Fragment A is now gone. I know this happens because onCreateView is called which probably means the Fragment's view is re-generated when FragmentTransaction.replace is called.

Is there a way where I can keep my fragments around instead of having them re-generate their views when FragmentTransaction.replace is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fragmentTransaction.replace, use fragmentTransaction.show and fragmentTransaction.hide.

That will keep your fragments from being destroyed.